# Python-turtle: From math library: dist() causing loop to exit/freeze

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to make a game using Python (with turtle)
the aim of the game is to shoot the other person

The problem comes with the collision code. I am checking collisions with bullets using `dist()`, but that seems to cause the loop to exit/freeze (I don't really know which).

I've tried using distance formula instead of the function but that didn't change anything

Here is my code:

```
        bullet.forward(10)
        distancetop1 = dist(player1.pos(),bullet.pos())
        if self != player1 and distancetop1 < 2:
            bullet.clear()
            print("orange won!")
            exit()
        distancetop2 = dist(player1.pos(),bullet.pos())
        if self != player2 and distancetop2 < 2:
            bullet.clear()
            print("blue won!")
            exit()
```

My full code, if needed, is [here](https://repl.it/@SeamusDonahue/shoot-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With turtle don't put your key checks in a loop. Set them once then call `listen`. Use `mainloop` to keep the game running.

Try this code:

```
import turtle,random, math

sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.bgcolor("#000")

player1 = turtle.Turtle()
player1.color("#00f")
player1.speed(0)
player1.up()
player1.goto(-256,0)

player2 = turtle.Turtle()
player2.color("#ffa500")
player2.speed(0)
player2.up()
player2.goto(256,0)
player2.seth(180)

bullet1 = turtle.Turtle()
bullet1.color("#fff")
bullet1.speed(0)
bullet1.ht()
bullet1.up()
bullet1.active = False 

def dist(c1,c2):
   return math.sqrt((c1[0]-c2[0])**2 + (c1[1]-c2[1])**2)

def shoot(self):
    bullet = bullet1.clone()
    bullet.active = True
    bullet.goto(self.xcor(),self.ycor())
    bullet.down()
    bullet.seth(self.heading())
    while (bullet.xcor() < 600 and bullet.xcor() > -600) and (bullet.ycor() < 256 and bullet.ycor() > -256):
        bullet.forward(10)
        distancetop1 = dist(player1.pos(),bullet.pos())
        if self != player1 and distancetop1 < 5:
            bullet.clear()
            print("orange won!")
            exit()
        distancetop2 = dist(player2.pos(),bullet.pos())
        if self != player2 and distancetop2 < 5:
            bullet.clear()
            print("blue won!")
            exit()
    bullet.clear()
def p1right():
    player1.seth(0)
    player1.forward(4)
def p1left():
    player1.seth(180)
    player1.forward(4)
def p1up():
    player1.seth(90)
    player1.forward(4)
def p1down():
    player1.seth(270)
    player1.forward(4)
def p1shoot():
    shoot(player1)

def p2right():
    player2.seth(0)
    player2.forward(4)
def p2left():
    player2.seth(180)
    player2.forward(4)
def p2up():
    player2.seth(90)
    player2.forward(4)
def p2down():
    player2.seth(270)
    player2.forward(4)
def p2shoot():
    shoot(player2)

#while True:
sc.onkey(p1right,"D")
sc.onkey(p1left,"A")
sc.onkey(p1up,"W")
sc.onkey(p1down,"S")
sc.onkey(p1shoot,"space")

sc.onkey(p2right,"Right")
sc.onkey(p2left,"Left")
sc.onkey(p2up,"Up")
sc.onkey(p2down,"Down")
sc.onkey(p2shoot,"Return")
sc.listen()
sc.mainloop()
```

Comment: although that seems to also function instead of a while, it doesn't fix the problem of the bullet loop stopping at the first dist( ) function.

Comment: Answer updated. The `dist` method is only available in python 3.8. I had to write a custom `dist` function to test.

Comment: Awesome that works flawlessly, is there a way to make mainloop/onkey stuff stop when someone is hit? thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: If you want to keep the game going, use `return` instead of `exit()`

Comment: I wanted the game to stop completely when someone is hit. I have replaced exit() with return though.

Comment: nvm found the solution to that